# Mysql dump of single table

Tags: batch-file, mysql, mysql-backup

I am trying to make some normal (understand restorable) backup of mysql backup. My problem is, that I only need to back up a single table, which was last created, or edited. Is it possible to set mysqldump to do that? Mysql can find the last inserted table, but how can I include it in mysql dump command?  I need to do that without locking the table, and the DB has partitioning enabled.... Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL to get the last inserted / updated table :-

```
select table_schema, table_name 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema not in ("mysql", "information_schema", "performance_schema") 
order by greatest(create_time, update_time) desc limit 1;
```

Once you have the results from this query, you can cooperate it into any other language (for example bash) to produce the exact table dump).

Comment: Know that, but how to include this into windows bat file. Can you give me some example of win bat file where any myslq command is executed and the result of sql is used in mysql dump ??? I found `c:\<path-to-mysql>\bin\mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] --result-file="c:\<path>\backup.%DATE:~0,3%.sql" [database]` as an example

Comment: You using window? (I very bad in window ...). If you can set the query result into a variable ?

Comment: I need to pass that table name to mysql dump. All this must be performed in windows bat file, or somehow else, how can I schedule this job.

Comment: Sorry, is pretty easy to do the above in linux. But I have very little experience on bat. Probably you can open another question on bat.

Answer (score 0):

```
./mysqldump -uroot -proot mysql user > mysql_user.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

For dumping a single table use the below command.
Open cmd prompt and type the path of mysql like `c:\program files\mysql\bin`.
Now type the command:

```
mysqldump -u username -p password databasename table name > C:\backup\filename.sql
```

Here 
`username` - your mysql username
     `password` - your mysql password
     `databasename` - your database name
     table `name` - your table name
     `C:\backup\filename.sql` - path where the file should save and the filename.

If you want to add the backup table to any other database you can do it by following steps:

- login to mysql
- type the below command

  `mysql -u username -p password database name < C:\backup\filename.sql`